# Data driven testing using Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have to execute large number of test cases in parallel using TestNG and Selenium.    Each test case will be executed in different data set using Data driven testing. How to run these test cases in parallel in different machines? We can use Parallel attribute in TestNG but that is restricted to a single machine.

Can Selenium Grid tweaked and use in this purpose? If yes how to use this or any other suggestion?

I want examples of (https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp#when-to-use-it)

> To reduce the time it takes for the test suite to complete a test
>   pass.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's quite complicated it needs lot of understanding i haven't done it but i know that you need to create one root machine and rest machines will be childs of the parent machine then you can run the test scripts parallel but you need to make sure that those script shouldn't be dependent otherwise their will be lot of issue 
I have shared the link with you so you can check how you set up?

https://medium.com/@appening/how-to-run-your-test-on-multiple-machines-using-selenium-grid-3aa37d5d2b63

Comment: This will run same test cases in multiple machines. I want the same test cases using different data. Is it possible?

Comment: https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp#when-to-use-it. I am asking example of the 2nd point (To reduce the time it takes for the test suite to complete a test pass.)

Comment: yes it does work, but how can pass the different data to the same test cases and for that you need to use JUnit to pass the different data for same test cases

Comment: Can you give me some specific examples for the same.